# Regex extract multiple line from file

Tags: regex, linux, perl, sed, awk

How can I extract two fields from a given file "named.conf"?  I want the fields 'zone' and 'file'.

```
zone "example.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "db.example.com";
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-transfer { 10.101.100.2; };
};
```

Comment: (1) What do you want the output to look like? (2) Your title specifies "regex". Is that required? (3) What have you tried?

Comment: http://p3rl.org/BIND::Conf_Parser http://p3rl.org/BIND::Config::Parser http://p3rl.org/Net::DNS::ZoneFile::Fast is what I found after searching for `named.conf` on CPAN.

Comment: @Daxim - that should be an answer :)

Comment: This is great but i thought if possible i can make it in bash rather then download and install perl module etc..

Comment: Net::DNS::ZoneFile::Fast is not a module that'll work, FYI.  It's for parsing zone files not named.conf files.  [I know; I'm the current maintainer of it :-) ]

Comment: Reason i am asking this question because i want to check zone file validation using named-checkzone command which require two input domain name and zone file. Thats why i am trying to extract two field from named.conf file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^\s*\(zone\|file\) "\([^"]*\)".*/,//!d;//!d;s//\2/' named.conf
example.com
db.example.com
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this regex working? what is s//\2/ means?

Answer (score 2):

Try this quick & dirty (GNU) AWK program (save it as `zone-file.awk`):

```
/^zone/, /^}/ {
    if (NF == 4) {
        zone = $2
        next
    }

    if (NF == 2 && $1 == "file") {
        sub(";$", "", $2)
        print zone, $2
    }
}
```

It works for me as follows:

```
$ awk -f zone-file.awk /etc/named.conf
"." "named.ca"
"localhost" "localhost.zone"
[...]
```

Comment: I would simplify that a bit: `awk '$1 == "zone" || $1 == "file" {print $2}'`